# PostgreSQL 14.5: Should I create 2 indexes what overlap?

Tags: postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL 14.5 , SQL script

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contract_detail_revenue;
CREATE TABLE contract_detail_revenue
(
    id                    smallint,
    contract_id           smallint       not null,
    cancel_revenue_date   date,
    revenue_type          smallint       not null,
    employee_id           smallint,
    organization_unit_id  smallint,
    inventory_item_id     smallint,
    rate                  numeric(16, 4) not null,
    revenue_amount        numeric(16, 4) not null,
    cancel_revenue_amount numeric(16, 4) not null,
    description           character varying(512),
    sort_order            smallint       not null,
    tenant_id             smallint,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, tenant_id)
);


CREATE INDEX contract_detail_revenue_idx ON contract_detail_revenue (id, tenant_id);
COMMIT;
```

I am sure that I will query with `where` clause use `tenant_id` very much. Should I create another index

```
CREATE INDEX contract_detail_revenue_idx2 ON contract_detail_revenue (tenant_id);
```

?

Sample query:

```
SELECT * FROM contract_detail_revenue WHERE tenant_id = 42;
```

I have many queries likes this (multi-tenant system).

Comment: Depends on your queries. Show us the SQL and query plans using explain(analyze, verbose, buffers). By the way, are you sure about the smallint data types?

Comment: Yes, I use smallint.

Comment: Will you  also be querying very much on just id?  If not, then you can make the primary key be in the opposite order, `(tenant_id, id)` rather than creating an additional index.  But there is nothing wrong with two indexes, if both will be used.

Answer (score 1):

Your index `contract_detail_revenue_idx` is redundant, since the primary key will already create an index on these columns. Instead, create the primary key on `(tenant_id, id)` rather than `(id, tenant_id)`. The order is irrelevant for the uniqueness guarantee, but the resulting index will have `tenant_id` first, so that it can be used by queries that have only `tenant_id` in their `WHERE` condition.

My advice is to come up with the actual queries you need *before* you define indexes.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it don't has the limit like this(using the sample column to create index).

If you like or you need,you can do it.

But it better to if your query need, and you have to know that the size of two column's index(like contract_detail_revenue_idx) will lager then the one column(like contract_detail_revenue_idx2).

If where always like `where id = $ and  tenant_id = $`, mayber contract_detail_revenue_idx will helper.If you never use it this way, I recommend creating separate indexes for the two fields.